# How to set node attributes after using from_pandas_edgelist networkx

Tags: networkx, gephi

I have load a dataframe to networkx by using nx.from_pandas_edgelist

The dataset "main" is similar to below
[image]

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(main,source = "trader"
,target = "Countertrade",edge_attr = ['product','country','price'])
```

However, when I export G to graphml and load it in Gephi, all the nodes do not have weights.

In this case, where should I set up my price as weight? So the nodes can change it's size based on the value from weight? (Company A will be the largest as it has traded 30, Company C traded 23 and the last will be Company B traded 10)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Meant what output does `G['Company A']['Company B']['price']` give?

Comment: It outputs keyerror

Comment: hmm. it gives me 10. check for any spaces missed, etc. i see that the price is defined over every edge: `[degree for node1,node2,degree in G.edges(data=True)] `

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the best method is to create a dictionary and use the nx.set_node_attributes

Comment: But since you don't show how to use `nx.set_node_attributes` to do this, this isn't really an answer.